# Remove a specific URL from data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, url

In Python I've a dataframe that contains in a column two comma separated URLS (https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it) and another column where the urls I want to remove from all the dataframe are stored. How do I accomplish this?

Example code

```
df = df = pd.DataFrame({'urls':['https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it', 'http://blah.com'], 'urls2':['http://blah.net', 'https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it']})
df2 = df

for column in df:

    URLVal = df["url2"].values
    df2 = df2.replace(str(URLVal.values), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try replacing using a regex:

```py
df["urls"] = df["urls"].str.replace(r'(?:,\s*)?https?://pluto.it(?:,\s*)?', '', regex=True)
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWbNGH/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Comment: Hey TIm, thanks for the solution..maybe i should explain better my example. I recursively search URLS from a column in the dataframe and want to remove the found URL from all the dataframe

Comment: @perfectson The code in my answer will strip `https?://pluto.it` from the entire column in the data frame.

Comment: yes! Thanks, I did not explain well what i was trying to achive..I've no way to directly intervene on the url string as it is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain why

> I've tried the solution df.replace("https://pluto.it", "")

failed. In `pandas` there exist distinct methods, `pandas.DataFrame.replace` (for replacing whole elements) and `pandas.Series.str.replace` (akin to replace method of `str`, note that it pertains to Series, i.e. single column of DataFrame). Consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["ABC","ABCDEF","DEF"]})
print(df.replace("DEF","X"))  # holds ABC, ABCDEF, X
print(df.A.str.replace("DEF","X"))  # holds ABC, ABCX, X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df = df.replace(r"\s*(?:,\s*)?https://pluto\.it\b", "", regex=True)
df.replace(r"\s*(?:,\s*)?https://pluto\.it\b", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls':['https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it', 'http://blah.com'], 'urls2':['http://blah.net', 'https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it']})
df.replace(r"\s*(?:,\s*)?https://pluto\.it\b", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

So, if the initial dataframe looks like

```
                                 urls                               urls2
0  https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it                     http://blah.net
1                     http://blah.com  https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it
```

The output will be:

```
               urls             urls2
0  https://pippo.it   http://blah.net
1   http://blah.com  https://pippo.it
```

The `inplace=True` makes the changes directly to the dataframe, no need to reassign the variable.

The `\s*(?:,\s*)?https://pluto\.it\b` regex needs more attention:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and then zero or more whitespaces
- `https://pluto\.it` - a literal `https://pluto.it` string
- `\b` - a word boundary (used to match `it` but not `ita`, `it0`, `it_` etc.). **Note**: If you want to make sure there is end of string, use `$`. If you want to make sure there can be a whitespace or end of string only after the URL, use `(?!\S)` instead of `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of the string element to be replaced is always the same, you could also do it very easily and without Regex as follows:

```
df.replace("https://pippo.it, https://pluto.it", "https://pippo.it")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however the solution seems not to work

Comment: I quickly tried it out with the sample df you provided and it does work with my script. Could you let me know what kind of error is produced? Or is the result simply not stored? If latter is the case, bear in mind that you either need to assign df.replace to df again (via: df = df.replace(...)) or then to set inplace = True in the replace function.